# OpenSSL CSR adds prefix in custom attribute value

Tags: openssl, x509

I am creating an OpenSSL configuration that should assist in generating Certificate Signing Requests for Hyperledger Fabric Identity and TLS certificates (we cannot use Fabric CA in our organisation). My current config produces CSR like this:

```
openssl req -in ecdsa_ident_req.pem -text -noout
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: C=NL, L=RD, OU=ll, CN=33
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:d2:5b:38:77:b4:8e:1d:97:ab:fa:82:8a:5b:5e:
                    8f:d5:f4:8f:5a:7e:fb:0b:c1:1e:15:31:cf:e6:47:
                    9c:91:ce:5d:2b:9d:6b:7c:91:a9:ba:35:3f:7c:5c:
                    d9:a4:5d:d9:51:6e:65:73:a0:b3:c9:79:af:85:90:
                    a6:19:4e:76:f5
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        Attributes:
            Requested Extensions:
                X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                    CA:FALSE
                X509v3 Key Usage:
                    Digital Signature, Non Repudiation
                1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1:
                    .l{"attrs":{"abac.init":"true","admin":"true","hf.Affiliation":"","hf.EnrollmentID":"Admin","hf.Type":"user"}}
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Signature Value:
...
```

What is unexpected is the `.l` prefix in the value of the `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1` attribute.

What do I need to change in my setup to set the value to the JSON string without that `.l` prefix.

I am using openssl version

```
OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.2.1 30 Jan 2024)
```

I generated the CSR using

```
export ISHARE_ATTRS="{\"attrs\":{\"abac.init\":\"true\",\"admin\":\"true\",\"hf.Affiliation\":\"\",\"hf.EnrollmentID\":\"Admin\",\"hf.Type\":\"user\"}}"
openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf -new -newkey ec:ec_param.pem -section req_ecdsa_identity_admin -keyout ecdsa_ident_key.pem -out ecdsa_ident_req.pem
```

And the contents of `opensll.cnf` is:

```
# Barebones openssl configuration that can be used to generate CSRs for
# - iSHARE Satellite Identity/Enrollment certificates
# - iSHARE Satellite TLS certificates

# Resources/documentation
# - https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man5/config.html

openssl_conf = openssl_init

[ openssl_init ]
alg_section = evp_properties
engines = engines
oid_section = OID
providers = providers
random = random
ssl_conf = ssl_configuration

[ engines ]

[ evp_properties ]

[ OID ]
iShareAttributesExtension = 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1

[ providers ]

[ random ]

[ ssl_configuration ]
server = tls_server_config
client = tls_client_config
system_default = tls_system_default

[ tls_client_config ]
# configuration for SSL/TLS clients
RSA.Certificate = client-rsa.pem
ECDSA.Certificate = client-ecdsa.pem

[ tls_server_config ]
# configuration for SSL/TLS servers
RSA.Certificate = server-rsa.pem
ECDSA.Certificate = server-ecdsa.pem

[ tls_system_default ]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
MinProtocol = DTLSv1.2

[ req_dn_identity ]
countryName              = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default      = NL
countryName_min          = 2
countryName_max          = 2
localityName             = Locality Name (eg, city)
organizationalUnitName   = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
commonName               = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_max           = 64

[ req_dn_tls ]
countryName              = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default      = NL
countryName_min          = 2
countryName_max          = 2
localityName             = Locality Name (eg, city)
organizationalUnitName   = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
commonName               = Common Name (eg, hostname)
commonName_max           = 64

[ req_ecdsa_identity_admin ]
distinguished_name = req_dn_identity
req_extensions = x509v3_identity

[ req_ecdsa_identity_user ]
distinguished_name = req_dn_identity
req_extensions = x509v3_identity

[ req_ecdsa_identity_peer ]
distinguished_name = req_dn_identity
req_extensions = x509v3_identity

[ req_ecdsa_identity_orderer ]
distinguished_name = req_dn_identity
req_extensions = x509v3_identity

[ req_ecdsa_tls ]
distinguished_name = req_dn_tls
req_extensions = x509v3_ecdsa_tls

[ req_rsa_tls ]
distinguished_name = req_dn_tls
default_bits = 4096
req_extensions = x509v3_rsa_tls

[ x509v3_identity ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature,nonRepudiation
iShareAttributesExtension = ASN1:UTF8String:$ENV::ISHARE_ATTRS

[ x509v3_ecdsa_tls ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:FALSE
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, serverAuth

[ x509v3_rsa_tls ]
basicConstraints = critical, CA:FALSE
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, serverAuth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix is the type tag – the "`.`" is actually `0x0C`, which is **the ASN.1 DER tag for the UTF8String type;** and the "`l`" that follows is `0x6C`, which just happens to correspond to an ASCII letter, but in this context really means 108 – the length of your UTF8String value.

This is standard for all X.509v3 and CSR extensions – all of them encapsulate a tagged DER value, e.g. the "keyUsage" value has a BitString tag inside, the "basicConstraints" value has a Sequence tag, and so on.

The only difference is that the `openssl req` tool *knows how to display* the contents of "standard" extensions, while for unknown extensions it displays the raw contents – including their type tag if any.

The OpenSSL config language allows you to customize this tag value (ASN1_generate_nconf(3)), but doesn't have an easy option to outright remove it, simply because the value is expected to be valid DER (which is why you're using `ASN1:` in the first place – to produce a valid DER value!).

You *can* achieve this using the `DER:$ENV::ISHARE_ATTRS_HEX` specifier instead of `ASN1:` (note that it requires a *hex-encoded* string to be provided), but I strongly doubt that this will result in a valid request. If anything, I believe it will make the request *less* valid than what you currently have. (Or, if that's somehow "valid" per iSHARE, then iSHARE is doing weird things.)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. The CSR should be good enough to get me a certificate with the expected attributes.